# How to make Angular 5 application to be supported by old firefox?

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox

I need to my application in Angular 5 be supported by older firefox versions (43,44..). The problem exists when I have empty path in route like

```
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'view', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Then, application can't be loaded and I have an error about too much recursions. When I change path than it works, but it's not solution. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Those versions of Firefox are past End Of Life. They don't get security updates, not even in the Extended Support program. They should be considered walking security holes. People using them should be strongly encouraged to upgrade. You should not jump through hoops to make new code work on them.

Comment: I must, because still a lot of people using this versions and my app must be available for them. I agree that few features of my app can't work properly, but app must work.

Comment: @Algeroth Less than 0.1% of users are using these versions. I don't think that 'a lot of people are using these versions' is really applicable here.

Comment: My customer made task for me, that he can't run this app on his firefox ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to generate route for view path in your routing file like below

{
        path:'view',
        component: viewcompont //declare your component name
}

Comment: Yes, it's true. But then, I can't run my app by ex. localhost:4200 and I must always remember, to put 'view' into my url

Comment: import your routing file in app.module.ts and than use like
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/view', pathMatch: 'full'} and declare <router-outlet></router-outlet> in your root component.